# How can I give the sourcefilepaths to gcc?

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

How can I give my sourcepaths to `gcc`?

I have my `.c` files in source and test directory.

How can I give `gcc` the path to it? I`m compiling with a`makefile` and always get the message

> "no such file or directory test.c"

My directory structure:

```
make-directory|
              |
              |--source
              |
              |--Header
              |
              |--test
              |
              |--out
              |
```

as asked:

```
# makefile to generate UNIT-tests

# define any directories containing header files other than /usr/include
# TODO 

HEADERS =   :../CUnit/headers \
            CUnit/sources/Automated \
            CUnit/sources/Basic \
            CUnit/sources/Console \
            CUnit/sources/Curses \
            CUnit/sources/Framework \
            CUnit/sources/Test \
            CUnit/sources/Win \
            CUnit/sources/wxWidget \
            stub \
            ../source \
            test

SOURCES =   CUnit/headers \
            CUnit/sources/Automated \
            CUnit/sources/Basic \
            CUnit/sources/Console \
            CUnit/sources/Curses \
            CUnit/sources/Framework \
            CUnit/sources/Test \
            CUnit/sources/Win \
            CUnit/sources/wxWidget \
            stub \
            source \
            test


# define any libraries to link into executable:
#   if I want to link in libraries (libx.so or libx.a) I use the -llibname 
#   option, something like (this will link in libmylib.so and libm.so:
LIBS = 

#  TODO define the C source files
TST_SRCS = min.c max.c

SRCS = CUnit.c Automated.c Basic.c Console.c CUCurses.c CUError.c  Cunit_intl.c \
        MyMem.c TestDB.c TestRun.c Util.c wxWidget.c \
        $(TST_SRCS)


# define the C object files 
#
# This uses Suffix Replacement within a macro:
#   $(name:string1=string2)
#         For each word in 'name' replace 'string1' with 'string2'

#OBJ = $(SRCS:%.c=%.o)
OBJ = $(TST_SRCS:%.c=%.o)
#OBJ=$(join ($(SOURCES)), $(notdir $(SRCS:%.c=%.o))) 

# define the C compiler to use
CC = gcc
# define any compile-time flags
CFLAGS = -O0 -g -Wall -fmessage-length=0 -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage         
#TODO Linkerflags
LFLAGS = --coverage 

VPATH=source
# define the executable file,

TARGET = CUnit
all:    
    $(CC) -I $(HEADERS) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJ) -o $(TARGET) $(LFLAGS)
```

Comment: Please provide your Makefile

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `vpath` or `VPATH` in makefile to point to the directory containing the source files.

See the online [gnu make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/General-Search.html) here.